# How can I get only pictures from the facebook news feed using Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm looking at the Facebook Graph API and trying to pick out any pictures that a user has in their news feed.

I've found that if I use the API /me/feed I can get access to the entire feed.  Each entry in the returned data array has a field called "type" which describes what kind of object it is.  For example, I've seen the following:

```
"type": "status"
"type": "photo"
"type": "video"
etc...
```

Obviously I don't want the status, video or etc types and would like to filter out those results on the server but haven't figured out how.  I was hoping it'd be something as simple as adding a query string like ?type=photo but that isn't the case.

Is there any way to filter the feed on the server side so I don't need to get down a lot of data for a few pictures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easier to do in FQL than with the Graph API:

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, message, attachment, place, created_time, likes, description
  FROM stream WHERE source_id = me() AND actor_id = me() 
   AND attachment.fb_object_type = 'photo'
```

Comment: This doesn't return any data.  If I take out the attachment.fb_object_type='photo', the I see only posted links.  I think you are correct that FQL is the answer - I'm looking at the photo and album tables now.

Comment: This query does return photos. I was looking for photos posted by others on a fan page. What I have found is how the photo is posted depends on how it shows in FQL.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out FQL.  I have used a query similar to this to get the image links.

Comment: @brianestey It would be great to see the query that you ended up using.

Comment: @JoeMcBride I abandoned this project and haven't looked at this code in a while but I still have the code.  The query I've found inside is "SELECT pid, src, src_small, src_big, caption FROM photo WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner=me())".  I make no guarantees that it will work, but hopefully it gives you an idea of what your query should look like.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook has added a filter parameter to the `/me/home` endpoint so if you query `/me/home?filter=photos` you get only photos from the users `News Feed`